# Sudokus everywhere!

Tags: no-computers, sudoku

Every 9x9 box is a valid sudoku, making 9 sudokus in all. I'm not sure how hard it is as I started solving it with just a few clues, then added more whenever I got stuck. Enjoy!

[image]

Comment: yay! clue symmetry!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution:

> [image: sol]

Method:

> It is in fact much easier than most normal sudoku puzzles.
>
>
>  For example, the rows 1 2 3 in column 1 are 1 3 4, which tells us that the rows 10 11 12 in column 1 are also 1 3 4, in some order.
>
>
>  This gives us much more information than it appears.
>
>  For example, the column 10 of row 10 is 3, so in the columns 1 2 3 of row 10, there must also be a 3.
>
>  Combined with the last piece of information, we conclude that row 10 column 1 must be a 3.
>
>
>  With this kind of logic, I solved the whole puzzle without any of the tricky logics used in normal sudoku puzzles.
>
>  However, as the puzzle is huge, it is really labor intensive and very easy to make mistakes. I had to roll back several times because of errors. Other than that, I would say it's an easy puzzle.
>
>
>  Nevertheless, I appreciate the effort put into creating it, and I hope to see some more tricky versions. (But perhaps slightly smaller in scale?)

Comment: (+1) Was about 70% there and you beat me to it, well done! :)

Comment: @Sciborg Sorry for that :P This also happened to me several times...

Comment: No worries! I always have a blast doing these. This one was especially fun because of the multiple grid logic.

Comment: Nice job! I will try and make any future sudokus tougher and smaller. ;-)